# Is some way out of box resolve bindings inside property using ninject

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, properties, ninject

> **I am interesting about way out of box to resolve this example:**
>
> example:

```
class A { public B someProperty {get;set;} }

class B { public IResolve needResolve {get;set;} }

class C:IResolve {}

class D:IResolve {}
```

> When I set binding like:

```
 IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IResolve>().To<C>();
```

> And when I Get type 'A'

```
var res = kernel.Get<A>();
```

> should be :

```
res.someProperty.needResolve.GetType() // typeof(C)
```

**PS: I read about way to resolve property by [inject] attribute. But it works only with a property that type which we try to resolve.
I understand how I can resolve it(e.g: Reflection), but I try to found the best solution**

Comment: Constructor injection would be way better in this case. I guess if it is not an option for you @JanMuncinsky 's answer is the correct one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works for me:

```
class A
{
    [Inject]
    public B someProperty { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    [Inject]
    public IResolve needResolve { get; set; }
}
```

`res.someProperty.needResolve` is of type C.